# How to get the count of only those rows from one table that belong to a certain row of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return 2 counts for each panel in my query and think I'm not using it correctly/not informing mysql to do this for each record:

```
SELECT user_id, panel_name AS panels,
(SELECT COUNT(country_id) FROM country_panel WHERE country_id = 231 ) AS gb_count,
(SELECT COUNT(country_id) FROM country_panel WHERE country_id = 232 ) AS us_count
FROM panels
```

At the moment this is returning a row with each panel, but the counts are counts of the whole database. I would like to count per panel.

Comment: @SalmanA Please can you elaborate on this, perhaps with an example?

Comment: Your SQL makes no sense, can you give a sample result you would like to get? what is the connection between panels and country_panels

Comment: @MaxT Every panel, has many country_panel (these are countries associated with a panel) I would like to return a row for every panel, and then include a count of the countries for that panel, in this case it would be a 1 or a 0 depending on whether that panel had a gb/us country linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you just need to specify additional criteria inside the WHERE clause of each subquery:

```sql
SELECT user_id
     , panel_name AS panels
     , (SELECT COUNT(country_id) FROM country_panel WHERE country_panel.panel_id = panels.id AND country_panel.country_id = 231) AS gb_count
     , (SELECT COUNT(country_id) FROM country_panel WHERE country_panel.panel_id = panels.id AND country_panel.country_id = 232) AS us_count
FROM panels
```

I guessed the column names.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT panels.user_id, 
       panels.panel_name AS panels,
       SUM(country_panel.country_id = 231) AS gb_count,
       SUM(country_panel.country_id = 232) AS us_count
FROM panels
JOIN country_panel ON country_panel.panel_id = panels.id -- check the relation !!!
WHERE country_panel.country_id IN (231, 232) -- may be skipped, but speed descrease
GROUP BY panels.user_id, 
         panels.panel_name AS panels
```